# Explode dictionary list in python

Tags: python, dictionary, explode

I have a list of dictionaries and for a key in dictionaries I have a list of nested dictionary which I want to explode to multiple elements. Consider the below input which I want to convert to the output as shown below:

**Input:**

```
[
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": [
      {
        "k1": "v1",
        "k2": "v2",
        "k3": "v3"
      },
      {
        "k1": "p1",
        "k2": "p2",
        "k3": "p3"
      }
    ],
    "key4_a1": "b1",
    "key4_a2": "b2"
  }
]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": {
      "k1": "v1",
      "k2": "v2",
      "k3": "v3"
    },
    "key4_a1": "b1",
    "key4_a2": "b2"
  },
  {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": {
      "k1": "p1",
      "k2": "p2",
      "k3": "p3"
    },
    "key4_a1": "b1",
    "key4_a2": "b2"
  }
]
```

I cannot use Pandas dataframe to explode as the keys are not unique and further requirement won't allow me to use Pandas. Is there any way to explode this without using Pandas ?

Comment: Where are "a" and "b" coming from?

Comment: Sorry there was some mistake, "a" and "b" won't come, I have updated the question

Comment: How many layers of nesting will you have?

Comment: Only one layer I guess